# How to concatenate in $.getJSON?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a web app that include some Ajax inside.
I need to pass 2 variables to external PHP
How do I add another concatenation for my second value ?

Here is my code

```
$.getJSON('myphp.php?value1=" . $rowData['value1'] .
```

I need to pass to the PHP file also 'value2'
But I can't figure out how to concatenate right the second value and what is the right syntax

Thank in advance

Abraham

Comment: that's javascript. why are you using PHP operators in javascript? JS uses `+`, not `.`

Comment: Wrong operator for JS. As @MarcB said.

Comment: Are you looking to add a php var - `$.getJSON('myphp.php?value1=<?=$rowData['value1']?>&value2=<?=$rowData['value2']?>', ...` or `$.getJSON('myphp.php?value1=<?php echo $rowData['value1']?>&value2=<?php echo $rowData['value2']?>', ...` or a js var -  `$.getJSON('myphp.php?value1='+value1+'&value2='+value2, ...`?

Comment: I believe it is a PHP var.
$rowData represent a mysql table that my web app is connected to.
So actually I need something like this:

$.getJSON('myphp.php?value1=<?=$rowData['value1']?>&value2=<?=$rowData['value2'‌​]?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better way to do the same:

```
var val1 = <?php echo $rowData['value1']; ?>;
var val2 = <?php echo $rowData['value2']; ?>;
var val3 = <?php echo $rowData['value3']; ?>;

$.getJSON('myphp.php', {value1: val1, value2: val2, value3: val3}, function(data){

 // Success Callback
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$.getJSON( "test.js", { value1: $rowData['value1'], value2: $rowData['value2'] } )
```

Comment: how can you merge PHP variables with JS?